# Image and Font not sharp on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, bootstrap-4, windows-10

My fonts and images look blurry on Firefox and Chrome on my PC. but looks amazing on Safari, Firefox and Chrome on my Mac

Image below is my font

[image]

This image is from my SVG image file

[image]

Does it have to do with my CSS? I have this in my CSS

```
body,
html {
  font-family: Roboto, arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Not sure whats going on here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you changed something on your PC. Go to **Start**, type in **Adjust the appearance and performance on Windows**, and put on **Adjust for best appearance**. That should help, I had the same problem.

Comment: hmm, i tried it. but not much difference